# AngularJs ng-init function With PHP parameter in Wordpress

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I need to pass php variable as parameter to angulaJs function. But I am not getting the Wordpress parameter in Angularjs function. I am getting `undefined` in AngularJs function.

My code :

```
<div class="ind-wrapper" data-ng-controller="mainController" data-ng-init="init(<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>)">
</div>
```

AngularJs function:

Here I am getting title name is undefined

```
$scope.init = function (titlename) 
    {
        alert(titlename)
    }
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode echoed variable properly, for example using `json_encode` function which will ensure that your title has proper quotes:

```
data-ng-init="init(<?php echo json_encode(get_the_title()); ?>)"
```

If you know that the title doesn't contain special characters or other quotes you can also simply do this:

```
data-ng-init="init('<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>')"
```